# systemd StandardOutput to a file _and_ to the journal?

Tags: logging, systemd, journald

I am regularly doing a long running (~5 day) data processing programme. I'm using Ubuntu and running the command with a systemd transient task via `systemd-run --unit data_import /path/to/my-script.sh`. It's working well. I can look at the logging standard output of the script with `journalctl -u data_import.service`.

I would like the stdout (& stderr) from the script to be saved to a file as well as the systemd journal. I see that `systemd-run --unit data_import -p "StandardOutput=file:/path/my-logging-file.txt …` will save stdout to that file. However it won't log to the journald. I tried to provide the argument twice `systemd-run -p "StandardOutput=file:/path/my-logging-file.txt" -p "StandardOutput=journal" …`, but that didn't work.

Is it possible with systemd to log the stdout to a file *and* to the systemd journal? (likewise for stderr?)

Ubuntu 18.04 & 20.04, systemd v250. or v245 etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess we can't but found one reference https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#StandardOutput= which might help (pay attention to **Takes one of** string).

> Controls where file descriptor 1 (stdout) of the executed processes is
> connected to. **Takes one of** inherit, null, tty, journal, kmsg,
> journal+console, kmsg+console, file:path, append:path, truncate:path,
> socket or fd:name.

Though we can change default standard output type.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to create a log file directly into your script and add the info every time necessary ? I know its pretty obvious but I'm curious to see if it works.

For example with bash, directly in your script :

```
# Declaration
LOG=/var/log/your_script_log.log
# Or with a date 
TODAY=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
LOG=/var/log/your_script_log-$(TODAY).log
...
# Beginning of main script
echo -e $TODAY > $LOG
...
# Every time needed during the script
if [[ $state == *"stopped"* ]];then
    echo "A very important message." >> $LOG
...
```

With a system like this you will need to configure a logrotate to avoid the hundreds logs after a few month.

Comment: Yes I _could_ do that, but that's implementing half of what `systemd` I supposed to do (AIUI). I want to know if systemd can do it.

Answer (score 0):

@Amandasaurus Okay I understand. Then I recommend you create a service file under "/etc/systemd/system/[The name of your script].service" and add the minimum necessary information :

```
[Unit]
Description=*The name of your script*

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/my-script.sh
ExecStop=/bin/kill $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Type=simple
StandardOutput=/path_to_log/service.log
StandardError=/path_to_log/service_error.log

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And then configure a logrotate or add "append" to the StandardOutput argument. After that do the following :

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start *The name of your service*
```

To enable start at boot of your service :

```
systemctl enable *The name of your service*
```

Source of the log argument in service file : [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321709/redirect-systemd-service-logs-to-file)

Comment: This doesn't log to the journal though. It *only* logs to the files.

Comment: Indeed ! Reading my answer one year after I realize I'm not solving the issue.